# Android button - maintain image transparency across press states

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

A noob quesiton here:

I have a button with a partially-transparent PNG background. I am trying to maintain the transparency of the button across different press states. The problem is: when I apply a gradient to the background image (to indicate the button is pressed), the gradient darkens the whole 'block of space' occupied by the image, not just the image itself.

How do I keep the transparent parts of the image transparent? Thanks in advance...

**selector_button_singleplayer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_singleplayer" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_button_singleplayer" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_button_singleplayer" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_singleplayer" />
```

**gradient_button_singleplayer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/button_singleplayer"/>
</item>
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="#880f0f10" android:centerColor="#880d0d0f" android:endColor="#885d5d5e"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

**my button:**

```
<Button android:id="@+id/main_menu_choose_single_player"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
android:background="@drawable/selector_button_singleplayer"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for ImageButton

set android:src as button_singleplayer

and your gradient_button_singleplayer.xml will be

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="#880f0f10" android:centerColor="#880d0d0f" android:endColor="#885d5d5e"/>
    </shape>
```

and your selector_button_singleplayer.xml will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_button_singleplayer" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_button_singleplayer" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

and your imageButton will be

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/main_menu_choose_single_player"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
android:background="@drawable/selector_button_singleplayer"
android:src="@drawable/button_singleplayer"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that answer is on the right track. However, now the gradient is ONLY applied to the background and the image itself remains totally untouched. Before the whole block was darkened, now only the transparency of the image is affected. But maybe I can work it out from there. Thanks for your answer.